# How to create and reuse a package in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, package

I have two kotlin files : *mylib.kt* and *main.kt*

*mylib.kt* is:

```
package mylib

fun hello() {
    println ("Hello")
}
```

and *main.kt* is:

```
import mylib.hello

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   hello()
}
```

I compile mylib with : kotlinc mylib.kt -d mylib.jar
 And main.kt with : kotlinc main.kt  -classpath mylib.jar  -include-runtime -d main.jar

I run java with: java  -jar main.jar
 and got :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mylib/MylibKt
    at MainKt.main(main.kt:4)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mylib.MylibKt
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more
```

What I did wrong ?
 Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kotlinc does not generate a jar that is executed via `java -jar` command.  Instead, use `java -classpath mylib.jar:main.jar MainKt`.

Comment: Glad to be of help. If a answer addresses the posed problem, then please accept the answer as it helps future posters seeking answers to similar problems.  If this wasn't the case, then please comment on why the answer does not address the problem.

Comment: Your message was of great help for me : I could not have guess to write MainKt instead main.

Comment: Please don't post Thank you comments.  Instead, accept an answer (as an original poster) or up vote a comment. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer.